# Jenkins: Remove Whitespace from ${ITEM_FULL_NAME}

Tags: jenkins, whitespace

I have a Jenkins server built on a Windows PC, when it builds my project it adds the word Pipeline with a space character separator to the project in the workspace.  The value `${ITEM_FULL_NAME}` is safe from an OS point of view but I have a problem with a process (Xilinx Memory Interface Generator) that runs in the pipeline that cannot cope with spaces in the path (it is bad that that process cannot cope with space characters in directories but I am stuck with it).  Is there a way to ensure the generated `${ITEM_FULL_NAME}` variable does not contain space characters?

I have tried to work around the issue by creating a Power Shell script to rename the directory using the underscore character but as feared I cannot do this as a process is running on the folder.

I have looked at the Whitespace plugin but I think this is for inputs into the pipeline not for what Jenkins generates.

I also looked at Restrict Project Naming but again think this is for project input and not what is generated by Jenkins.

Any suggests gratefully received; I am new to Jenkins so if you have a solution it might need spelling out, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `trim` to remove the white spaces:

```
ITEM_FULL_NAME= ITEM_FULL_NAME.trim()
```

Another way :
If the variable is a parameter variable then you can use below:

```
parameters { string(defaultValue: "", description: '', name: 'ITEM_FULL_NAME', trim: true) }
```

Comment: The `${ITEM_FULL_NAME}` variable is used in the Jenkins project config.xml file in the line `<workspaceDir>D:/Jenkins/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}</workspaceDir>` so the trim method won’t work.

Comment: @X-Peri-MENTAL : Cant you read this variable in the pipeline and do a trim before getting used